# Example of strict inequality in special case of fatou's lemma.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Give an example of sequence of events $\{A_n\}$ such that the following inequalities are strict
$P(\lim\inf A_n) \le \lim\inf P(A_n) \le \lim\sup P(A_n) \le P(\lim\sup A_n)$.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_n=\{0\}$ if $n$ is odd and $A_n=\{1\}$ if $n$ is even.

This with $P(\{0\})=\frac13$ and $P(\{1\})=\frac23$.

(in fact: $2$ disjoint events with unequal positive probability)

Then $\liminf A_n=\varnothing$ and $\limsup A_n=\{0,1\}$.

Consequently $P(\liminf A_n)=0$ and $P(\limsup A_n)=1$.

Next to that $\liminf P(A_n)=\frac13$ and $\limsup P(A_n)=\frac23$.